# TakeScreenshot with AWS Device Farm and UIAutomator 2

Tags: android, android-uiautomator, aws-device-farm

I've got a problem with my automated UI tests using AWS device farm. I tried to create a new UIAutomator 2 test. This works fine on my device and my development machine.

No I created a new test run in AWS device farm to run this test on all the other devices creating screenshot output. The problem here seems to be in taking the screenshots.

With Automator 2 I take my screenshots using automator frameworks `UIDevie.takeScreenshot` method. This method takes a `File` as parameter.

As described in [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-uiautomator.html)  I tried to store the file using the `/sdcard/` folder as well as `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. None of those directories seem to work.

**With `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` I get the following LOG:**

```js
Error UiAutomatorBridge java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/test-screenshots/coupondetail-screen-2.png: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

**Using `/sdcard/` I get the following LOG:**

```js
Error UiAutomatorBridge java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/test-screenshots/coupondetail-screen-2.png: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Also I used the following reference implementation:
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-device-farm-sample-app-for-android/blob/master/app/src/androidTest/java/com/amazonaws/devicefarm/android/referenceapp/Util/ScreenShot.java

Answer (score 0):

It does seem to be a problem regarding the new permission system up from Android 6.x where a user needs to accept critical permissions directly. For tests there is a workaround where you can accept permissions (such as WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) using adb shell command:

[How to manage Runtime permissions android marshmallow espresso tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32787234/how-to-manage-runtime-permissions-android-marshmallow-espresso-tests)