# granting permissions automatically on android emulator

Tags: android, automation, android-emulator

I'm just wondering if there is any way to grant permission on emulator automatically. I want to accept and grant any permission pop up on Android Emulator. I know is now safe but I want to do this for my experience.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to do this automatically allow runtime permissions though you can do this during [instrumentation testing of app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34947797/4936904) and via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32787234/4936904).

One way is go to setting => apps and open your app and then grant the permission